# how to evaluate expression to truewhen both the operands are false

Tags: apex, visualforce, operators

```
<div id="contentToToggle" style="display:{!if(showContent && showContentreplica,"block","none")};">
    dont have duplicates
</div>

{
showContent =false;
showContentreplica = false;
}
```

in controller i added above conditions.
i want to display above div,if both operands are false.need help,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both are false and you need to display a div,you have to use a not operator for the variables.

```
<div id="contentToToggle" style="display:{!if(!showContent && !showContentreplica,"block","none")};">
    dont have duplicates
</div>
```